# How to avoid hard coding in python for replacing short form words and also young words?

Tags: python

```
text = 'hey, c ya nxt week. TTYL n tq'
x = text.replace('ya', 'you').replace('bcs', 'because').replace('nxt', 'next').replace(' n ', ' and ').\
    replace('tq', 'thanks').replace('ur', 'your').replace('c', 'see').replace('nah', 'no').\
    replace('thx', 'thanks').replace('dope', 'exciting').replace('bruh', 'dude').\
    replace('nope', 'no').replace('ppl', 'people').replace('pls', 'please').replace('U', 'you').\
    replace('TTYL', 'talk to you later').replace('OMG', 'oh my god').replace('4', 'for').\
    replace('24/7', 'on the regular').replace('TBH', 'to be honest').\
    replace('YOLO', 'you only live once').replace('ATM', 'at the moment').\
    replace('BRB', 'be right back').replace('BTW', 'by the way').replace('GTG', 'got to go').\
    replace('IDK', 'I do not know').replace('IKR', 'I know right').\
    replace('OMW', 'on my way').replace('tmrw', 'tomorrow')
print('Original text: ', text)
print('Non-shortform text: ', x)
```

I am new to python. I have query regarding to un-hardcoding the short form and young words in python script. Currently I wrote the code as shown. Anyone who can teach would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary

```
d = {
    'YOLO': 'you only live once',
    'ATM': 'at the moment',
    'BRB': 'be right back',
    # ...
}
text = 'hey, c ya nxt week. TTYL n tq'
for key, value in d.items():
    text = text.replace(key, value)
print(text)
```

Comment: This still is hard-coded and actually your code does not change the string, you are missing and assignment `text = text.replace(key, value)`

Comment: @DaniMesejo Thanks, I edited in the assignment. How is this hard-coded? He could change the dictionary easily or pass in a different one if this was a function

Comment: Yes this solution is better, but this still would imply he need to change the file to add a new entry or modify an existing one

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is not a complete answer, just you showing you a way how to solve it efficiently.

Firstly you can make use of Regexes. You have to learn about regular expressions deeply first. An example: Such as `tq` and `thx` both expand to `thanks`. So try a regex replace:

```
import re
text = re.sub('tq|thx','thanks',text)
```

Secondly define dictionary of regexes:

```
rdict = {
'tq|thx': 'thanks'
...
}
```

and so on. Then replace using:

```
for x,y in rdict.items():
  text = re.sub(x,y,text)
```

Thirdly you can look for alternative libraries to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to decouple and remove hard-coding, you should do something like this:

```
import csv

replacements = {}
with open('replacements.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        replacements[row['original']] = row['replacement']


def replace_all(txt, rep):
    for o, r in rep.items():
        txt = txt.replace(o, r)
    return txt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = 'hey, c ya nxt week. TTYL n tq'
    res = replace_all(text, replacements)
    print(res)
```

**Output**

```
hey, see you next week. talk to you later and thanks
```

Where *replacements.csv* is a file like the one below:

```
original,replacement
ya,you
bcs,because
nxt,next
 n , and 
tq,thanks
ur,your
c,see
nah,no
thx,thanks
...
```

This way you don't need to change your code file to add or modify a new entry. The choice of csv is for the purpose of showing the principle of separating you data from your code, any other appropriate format will do.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope** this help you. using a `Dictionary` is ***pretty simple***.

```
mydict = {"ya":"you","bcs":"because", "nxt":" next", " n ":" and ", "tq":"thanks", "ur":"your", "c":"see", "nah":"no", "thx":"thanks", "dope":"exciting", "bruh":" dude", "nope":"no", "ppl":" people", "pls":"please", "U":"you", "TTYL":"talk to you later", "OMG":"oh my god", "4":"for", "24/7":"on the regular", "TBH":"to be honest", "YOLO":"you only live once", "ATM":"at the moment", "BRB":"be right back", "BTW":"by the way", "GTG":"got to go", "IDK":"I do not know", "IKR":"I know right", "OMW":"on my way", "tmrw":" tomorrow"}

text = "hey, c ya nxt week. TTYL n tq"
print('Original text: ', text)

for k, v in mydict.items():
    text = text.replace(k, v)

print('Non-shortform text: ', text)
```

**[RESULT]:**

> ```
> Original text:  hey, c ya nxt week. TTYL n tq
> Non-shortform text:  hey, see you  next week. talk to you later and thanks
> ```

**[EDIT]:**

For a *clean code*, you can also save the `dictionary` value in a file (i.e **Excel *.xlsx**), and then *import* it to your code.

[image]

> ```
> import pandas
> df = pandas.read_excel('sample.xlsx') #import data from an Excel file 
> df = df.astype(str)
>
> text = "hey, c ya nxt week. TTYL n tq"
> print('Original text: ', text)
>
> for index, row in df.iterrows():
>     text = text.replace(row['Short'], row['Message'])
>
> print('Non-shortform text: ', text)
> ```

Comment: @Ain , Your are welcome. So, you can checkmark it as "Accepted Answer", https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer